# Date Validator in asp form

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have used the following code to validate a date in a textbox, but it is not working. I don't know, why.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="*Invalid DateTime"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox5"
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Please let me know where I am wrong or what I have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use compare validator instead of customer validator. For Custom validator you have to write your own function but compare validator provides this functionality.

```
<asp:CompareValidator
id="dateValidator" runat="server" 
Type="Date"
Operator="DataTypeCheck"
ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date.">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use compare validator to validate date, a simple and elegant solution.

```
<asp:CompareValidator
id="CompareValidator"
runat="server" 
Type="Date" 
Operator="DataTypeCheck"
ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
ErrorMessage="*Invalid DateTime">
</asp:CompareValidator>
```

The Type="Date" tells the validator to check if the input is a valid date or not.